# How to get client IP address in service(DAO) class in java

Tags: java

Here is my Method

```
public synchronized void updateCompanyByNameandUrl(String companyName, String companyUrl)
{

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
    Connection con = null;
    Connection globalconnection = null;
    String updateCompanyquery   = "update `anjo_company_master` set URL = ? where COMPANY_NAME=?";
    String updateGlobalCompQuery= "update `anjo_company_master_global` set URL = ?, USER_IP = ? where  COMPANY_NAME=?"; 
    try
    {
        ***InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String userIp = localhost.getHostAddress().trim();***
        con = SQLHikariConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();

        ps = con.prepareStatement(updateCompanyquery);              

        ps.setString(1, companyUrl.trim());
        ps.setString(2, companyName.trim());
        ps.executeUpdate(); 

        //Updating companyUrl in Global Master also
        globalconnection = connFactory.getGlobalCompanyConnection();
        ps1 = globalconnection.prepareStatement(updateGlobalCompQuery);

        ps1.setString(1, companyUrl.trim());
        ps1.setString(2, userIp.trim());
        ps1.setString(3, companyName.trim());
        ps1.executeUpdate();    

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOG.info(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if (con != null)    
                con.close();
            if (ps != null) 
                ps.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here because of

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String userIp = localhost.getHostAddress().trim();
```

I didn't get userIp I got serverIp

But I get ServerIP not Client IP 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want client IP request scope object is required here. otherwise, add extra parameter into your DAO method and get ClientIP from the request object, pass while calling the DAO method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer How can I get the client IP request scope object?

Comment: I don't want to add extra parameter in DAO method because it's related to many other classes

Comment: @KanchiKatkar Please, refer to this [link](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/03/httpservletrequest-interface-with-example.html) to see some examples of HTTP Requests in java.

Comment: Are you working on a Web Application?

Comment: Yes, It's a web Application

Comment: Ok, are you using Servlets or an MVC framework like Spring to ease processing of request/response cycles?

Comment: MVC framework like Spring

Comment: Which specific framework are you using? Spring or another? Can you also edit your question showing how you attend this request? In that way, we can provide more accurate help.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza   Spring framework

Comment: This is done, I handle it in javascript, whenever the call goes from Javascript I get userIp. Thanks, everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

please set the `HttpServletRequest` object into the DAO class before calling the DAO method.

```
Use the below code.


Class Test  extends HttpServlet {

               protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Client IP   " + request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For"));
    TestDAO dao = TestDAOImpl();
     dao.setHttpServletRequest(request);
     dao.xxxxx(xx,xx)\\call your method like this

    }

        }

    Class TestDAOImpl implements TestDAO { 

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public void setHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
    }

    //write your method here.
    public <?> doSomthing(){

       String clientIP= this.request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
       //d
}
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to implement in Service class only, how can I get request object scope
it's showing an error.

Comment: X-Forwarded-For may not show the actual requestor IP([ref.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14528/224567)), I would prefer using of `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I am using spring framework so when request passing to service class, service class don't use HttpServletRequest

Comment: Then it easy you can inject the HttpServletRequest object using Autowire.if you don't want to use autowire use the below code to get current request scope.

Comment: public static HttpServletRequest getCurrentHttpRequest() {
  RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
  if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
   HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
   return request;
  }
  return null;
 }